# What are the abi rules for return struct in the rust language

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, llvm-ir, abi

I want to Understand the rules of rust when processing struct return values in x86_64. By observing the following examples, I still cannot find the Abi rule of rust.

example1:

```
// 12Bytes
pub struct test_struct {
   a: i32,
   b: i32,
   c: i32,
}

pub fn foo() -> test_struct {
   let data = test_struct {
       a: 0,
       b: 1,
       c: 2,
   };

   data
}
```

This function in llvm ir is as follows:

```
define void @_ZN7example3foo17h4c785e31173cde01E(ptr sret(%test_struct)
```

We can see that the return value can be passed through the first sret parameter.

example2:

```
// 12Bytes
pub struct test_struct {
   a: i64,
   b: i32,
}

pub fn foo() -> test_struct {
   let data = test_struct {
       a: 0,
       b: 1,
   };

   data
}
```

This function in llvm ir is as follows:

```
define { i64, i32 } @_ZN7example3foo17h339bca89e202abeeE()
```

The return value is passed through the register.

example3:

```
// 8Bytes
pub struct test_struct {
   a: i32，
   b: i16,
   c: i16,
}

pub fn foo() -> test_struct {
   let data = test_struct {
       a: 0,
       b: 1,
       c: 2,
   };

   data
}
```

This function in llvm ir is as follows:

```
define i64 @_ZN7example3foo17h4c785e31173cde01E()
```

The return value is passed through the register.

Example 1 and Example 2 have the same return value size, but the way rust handles it is different, indicating that it is independent of the return value size.

The number of parameters in the return structure of Example 1 and Example 3 is the same, but the method of rust processing is different, indicating that it is independent of the number of parameters in the return structure.

This troubles me a lot, What are the abi rules for return struct in the rust language.

Comment: There is no rules you can follow, it depends on the concrete function and how it's called, that's what unspecified means.